# retrieving radioButton value from SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve a radioButton value from database from SQL Server Compact
But my code doesn't work and an error message shows (`unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe Command' to type 'System.IConvertible`) at line (`genderval = Convert.ToBoolean(gendercmnd);`)
.. what is wrong? 
thanks

```
if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    con.Open();

Boolean genderval = false;
SqlCeCommand gendercmnd = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT Gender FROM Std_info WHERE Std_id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
genderval = Convert.ToBoolean(gendercmnd);
if (genderval == true)
    Convert.ToBoolean(radioButton1.Checked);
else
    Convert.ToBoolean(radioButton2.Checked);  
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the final solution..!

```
//........ retrieving radioButton value ....... 

if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) 
      conn.Open(); 
try { 
       Boolean genderval = SqlCeCommand gendercmnd = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT Gender FROM Std_Info     WHERE Std_id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con); 

genderval = (Boolean)gendercmnd.ExecuteScalar(); 

if (genderval == true) 
    Convert.ToBoolean(radioButton1.Checked=true); 
else 
    Convert.ToBoolean(radioButton2.Checked = true); 
conn.Close(); 
     } 
catch (Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
```

thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try executing the command

```
genderval = (Boolean)gendercmnd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Also note that your query should be parameterized. Here is a complete example (using `SqlConnection` but if you replace the `Sql` classes with your provider classes it should work for you)

```
bool genderval;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("youeConnStr"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Gender FROM Std_info WHERE Id = @id", conn))
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));
        genderval = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is solved..!
//........  retrieving radioButton value  .......

`if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
     conn.Open();
  try
    {
       Boolean genderval = 
       SqlCeCommand gendercmnd = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT Gender FROM Std_Info WHERE Std_id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
       genderval = (Boolean)gendercmnd.ExecuteScalar();
       if (genderval == true)
           Convert.ToBoolean(radioButton1.Checked=true);
       else
           Convert.ToBoolean(radioButton2.Checked = true);
      conn.Close();
     }
    catch (Exception ex){MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);}`
thanks Tomek

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though you haven't actually queried the database yet, but are attempting to convert the actual *command* rather than the results gathered.

I'm not sure if the same works for SQL Server Compact but you need to either *ExecuteNonScalar* or *Execute* the command itself, retrieve the results and then run your comparison on that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing the command against the db and getting results? as that code doesn't look like it is doing it. I think you need to call ExecuteScalar() on the sqlcecommand.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is to get a result from the SQL server, and cast it as a boolean.

What you're actually doing is trying to convert your SQL command into a boolean.

What you need to do is actually open the connection to the SQL server and execute your query. But it's a bit more complex than that...

```
if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
   con.Open();

Boolean genderval = false;
SqlCeCommand gendercmnd = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT Gender FROM Std_info WHERE Std_id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);

gendercmnd.Connection.Open(); // Open the connection using the gendercmd string.
sqlReader = gendercmnd.ExecuteReader(); // Execute the read, which returns an SqlCEDataReader object that we can use to access the data. 


genderval = Convert.ToBoolean(gendercmndResult);
            if (genderval == true)
                Convert.ToBoolean(radioButton1.Checked);
            else
                Convert.ToBoolean(radioButton2.Checked);  
con.Close();
```

Now we need to take the value from the reader, and cast that as a boolean.

```
if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
   con.Open();

Boolean genderval = false;
String gendercmndResult = null;
SqlCeCommand gendercmnd = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT Gender FROM Std_info WHERE Std_id='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);

gendercmnd.Connection.Open(); // Open the connection using the gendercmd string.
sqlReader = gendercmnd.ExecuteReader(); returns an SqlCEDataReader object that we can use to access the data.

while (sqlReader.Read(){ //While the reader is reading...
    gendercmndResult = (sqlReader.GetString(0)); //Assign the returned value from the SQL server to a string called gendercmndResult
}


genderval = Convert.ToBoolean(gendercmndResult); //Now we can cast the string as a bool
            if (genderval == true)
                Convert.ToBoolean(radioButton1.Checked);
            else
                Convert.ToBoolean(radioButton2.Checked);  
con.Close();
```

Comment: "thank you for your discussion dear Joe Cullinan"
I made a simple Change and it worked!